# How to convert long type date into local Date Format in ng-repeat Angular js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, momentjs, angular-moment

I am using moment library for the date format. I can convert into controller, But I am not able to convert into HTML page. In Json is giving me date in long type. I want to convert in local time.Like Below format:

> {{moment(when.$date).format('YYYY-MM-DD@HH:mm')}}

**JSON**

```
{
"comments":
"when": {
"$date": 1536920319204
 }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
 $scope.responseData = response;
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr bolder>
                  <th class="bordered"> Date and Time </th>                     
                  <th class="bordered">Comments</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="myDetails in responseData ">
                  <td>
                    {{myDetails.when.$date}} //I want to convert into local time                  
                  </td>

                  <td>{{myDetails.comments}}</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
```

Kindly give idea how to convert into html page with ng-repeat.

Comment: What is the value of `when.$date` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi if you are using angular js you can use angular pipes to render your date

Expression

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

Example

```
 {{1288323623006 | date:'medium'}}: Oct 29, 2010 9:10:23 AM
 {{1288323623006 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}: 2010-10-29 09:10:23 +0530
 {{1288323623006 | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}: 10/29/2010 @ 9:10AM
 {{1288323623006 | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}}: 10/29/2010 at 9:10AM
```

replacing with your date

```
{{1536920319204 | date:'medium'}}: Sep 14, 2018 3:48:39 PM
{{1536920319204 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}: 2018-09-14 15:48:39 +0530
{{1536920319204 | date:'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}: 09/14/2018 @ 3:48PM
{{1536920319204 | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}}: 09/14/2018 at 3:48PM
```

Answer you want:

```
 {{1536920319204 |  date:'yyyy-MM-dd @ hh:mm'}}
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: Negi Rox Thanks for the answer

Comment: Could you we use without date:, I don't want to use date, because I am putting short functionality in the table based on date

Comment: you can use filter too no need to worry

Comment: Thanks for the valuable time, I tried with filter. But filter was not working in this case.